# I want to use flip page in pdf Viewer in android studio

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfviewer

I have created android app for pdf file but it only displaying simple view.
Actually I want to add flip page in my android pdf View. My PDFViewer code is:
and I also want to add functionality of searching page number (go to a specefic page through search).

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mnaum.quranasaanurdutrjuma;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
PDFView pdfView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pdfView=(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("parah1.pdf").load();


    new RetrievePDFStream().execute("http://ancestralauthor.com/download/sample.pdf");
    }



    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream>{

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream=null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200){
                    inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my XML file of Main Activity

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Comment: Did you do that?

Comment: No, I've still facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you do that?
I am also looking for this.

Comment: @SujeetKumar No, I didn't find any other solution yet.